# How do I implement Iterable in a class that has an ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I am going to have a class that has a ArrayList people field
I want clients of this class to be able to iterate over those objects.
How do I do this?  Do I just return people.iterator(); ?

for example, in the client I want to be able to do this:

```
for( Person p : people ) {
    // do something
}
```

Is this what I need in my class?

```
public class People  implements Iterable<Person> {

private ArrayList<Person> people;

@Override
public Iterator<Person> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return people.iterator();
}
```

Comment: *"Is this what I need in my class?"* ... Erm, we don't know, is it? That will certainly return an `Iterator` from the private `ArrayList`.

Comment: Can who ever down voted my question, please let me know why?  I certainly don't intend on asking dumb questions.  I think from the answers below, I now understand a bit more about the implications of the above code in my question,  but I am not sure what other research I should have done or what what was unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent modification to the list itself via the iterator, just delegate `iterator()` to an unmodifiable list like this:

```
public class People implements Iterable<Person> {

    private ArrayList<Person> people;

    @Override
    public Iterator<Person> iterator() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(people).iterator();
    }

}
```

Otherwise, what you have is fine.

Note, however, that unless `Person` is immutable, there is nothing you can do to prevent a caller from modifying the `Person` objects themselves. If that's OK, then no big deal. If that's a problem, then you could create a deep copy of `people` and return an iterator to that.

If you want the returned iterator to reflect modifications to the `Person`s but not to allow changing of the `Person`s, or if a deep copy is too expensive or unnecessary, you could create an `ImmutablePerson` that extends `Person` and wraps a `Person` but does not allow modification via setters, and return a list of those wrapped around the actual `Person` objects.

Comment: Thanks Jason , you helped me again.  Looking at the places in my client code that loop thru the persons in people, this is exactly the functionality I wanted to push down into the class in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The enhanced for loop requires an array or `Iterable`. `Iterable` is required to have `iterator(` that returns a reasonable iterator that has useful meaning in regard to your data.

You can now use the enhanced for loop and it is somewhat semantically correct. However, `Iterator` provides `remove(` so anyone using your iterator can remove things from your people list, which may not be what you want. Perhaps using `new ArrayList(people).iterator()` or `Collctions.unmodifiableList(people).iterator()` can work as you copy the list and get the iterator for *it*.

You can also provide `getPeople` by creating a getter that creates an `ImmutableList` or just a copy of your internal arrayList.

On another note, why not extend ArrayList if you need extra functionality? I haven't seen exactly what you're doing with it so I can only guess.

Comment: extending ArrayList<Person> was my original plan, but I then I thought encapsulating might be better.  The other reason , is because I need this to be Parcelable, and I could not figure out how to make an extension of ArrayList<Person> to be Parcelable (Person already is and I think I can figure out how to make the class with the ArrayList<Person> field Parcelable

Comment: @nPn OK. Remember that this can provide loss of control in terms of data protection due to the iterator's `remove(` method.

Comment: @hexafraction You could return `Collections.unmodifiableList(people).iterator()` (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide a getter for your People list:

```
public ArrayList<Person> get getPeople() {
   return people;
}
```

Comment: Returning a reference to the internal list may not be a good idea, perhaps a copy can be used instead?

Comment: @hexafraction why returning a reference o a list is not a good idea? it is not a static list.

Comment: We don't know for sure but the class the OP wrote could use it internally in places we can't see, as the code looks abridged.

Comment: At the bare minimum I would return `Collections.unmodifiableList(people);`, and only if a `Person` was immutable (and maybe go one step further and say only if `people` was `final`, depending on requirements).

Comment: I think I just have a lot to learn.  I think the answer is not to iterate outside the class?  I should provide the the class with a method to do what I want inside the class, right?